# get URL Parameters from current URL using Prototype JavaScript

Tags: javascript, url, parameters, prototypejs

I'm noob to JavaScript and want to use [Prototype JS](http://www.prototypejs.org) Framework to get some URL parameters.
Imagine I have the following URL on my current browser:

```
http://www.somewhere.com?param=abc
```

how can I get the value of `'param'` using any function or utility of [Prototype JS](http://www.prototypejs.org) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get query string values in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really don't need Prototype for this:

```
function get_param(param) {
   var search = window.location.search.substring(1);
   var compareKeyValuePair = function(pair) {
      var key_value = pair.split('=');
      var decodedKey = decodeURIComponent(key_value[0]);
      var decodedValue = decodeURIComponent(key_value[1]);
      if(decodedKey == param) return decodedValue;
      return null;
   };

   var comparisonResult = null;

   if(search.indexOf('&') > -1) {
      var params = search.split('&');
      for(var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
         comparisonResult = compareKeyValuePair(params[i]); 
         if(comparisonResult !== null) {
            break;
         }
      }
   } else {
      comparisonResult = compareKeyValuePair(search);
   }

   return comparisonResult;
}

var param_value = get_param('param'); //abc
```

Comment: hi jacob thank you for your reply, but i want to know is there any utility provided by Prototype js for this requirement ?

Comment: @dprima There is no utility that does this that I know of.

Comment: oh i see, thx jacob, both your answer and tim's below were true, but because you're the first, ill mark your answer as accepted

Comment: It may be worth calling `decodeURIComponent` on `key_value[1]` and ideally on `key_value[0]` before comparing it to the param.

Comment: @MikeSamuel I refactored the entire function to be a whole lot cleaner. I provided the original answer to this question over a year ago, so this should be a lot better... Any comments on the updated code are welcome! :)

Comment: @Jacob, looks correct.  Valueless attributes are treated as having a value of `undefined` which seems reasonable: `get_param('foo') === undefined` when `location.search === '?foo'`.

Answer (score 11):

Prototype.js DOES provide a utility:

```
uri.toQueryParams();
```

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on Scott's answer: to put the value of the URL variable 'param' into the javascript variable 'x' you would use Prototype like so:

```
x = document.URL.toQueryParams().param;
```